# Colab: Reunir módulos de Python en un único cuaderno

Tags: python, github, google-colab

Partiendo de varios ficheros *xxxx.py* ubicados en un misma carpeta, y que son invocados (todos menos uno) mediante sucesivos `import` desde el script principal, estoy tratando de construir un único cuaderno de Colab que albergue el contenido de todos ellos, de modo que ese cuaderno sea el único fichero con el que trabajar.

El problema me surge con uno de los ficheros, que en lugar de mediante un `import` "normal" es invocado de forma paramétrica en tiempo de ejecución, de esta manera:

```
muzero = MuZero("gomoku")
```

El script principal contiene lo siguiente (*game_name* sería "gomoku" en este caso):

```
def __init__(self, game_name, config=None, split_resources_in=1):
    game_module = importlib.import_module(game_name)
    self.Game = game_module.Game
    self.config = game_module.MuZeroConfig()
...
```

Y el módulo "gomoku" al que invoca incluye esto:

```
class MuZeroConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        self.seed = 0
        self.max_num_gpus = None
...

class Game(AbstractGame):
    def __init__(self, seed=None):
        self.env = Gomoku()
...
```

La pregunta es: Si todo el código está dentro del mismo fichero .py, ¿cuál es la sintaxis correcta para ejecutar esa parte del script? Dicho de otra manera, ¿qué debo poner en lugar de:

```
game_module = importlib.import_module(game_name)
```

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que quieres modificar. `gomoku`  es un clase que está definida en el mismo proyecto y se importa como lo has mostrado, de forma dinámica, no necesitas modificar nada, si tienes  gomoku.py en la carpeta games, el código la debería importar correctamente.

Comment: Es que no existe la carpeta games ni gomoku.py está en ella. El contenido de ese módulo está dentro del propio cuaderno.

Comment: Ok, ahora si.  El tema es dónde está el modulo, si en la misma carpeta de tu script, entiendo que debería funcionar bien, sino cualquier cosa puedes modificar el path de carga con `sys.path.append('path')` Revisa esto: https://www.programmersought.com/article/20492267227/

Comment: Creo que me expresé mal plantear la pregunta, así que he tratado de reformularla (ver arriba).